# Ayuda con Case anidado en SQL

Tags: sql

Necesito calcular el promedio de algunos campos en sql
Necesito el promedio de la columna Dia mientras tengan el mismo valor en el campo Semana, DiaSemana, Mes y Año

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe con esto

```html
CASE WHEN 
T.Semana = LEAD(T.Semana, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.Codigo) 
and T.DiaSemana = LEAD(T.DiaSemana, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.Codigo)
and T.Mes = LEAD(T.Mes, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.Codigo) 
and T.Año = LEAD(T.Año, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.Codigo) 
THEN avg(cast(T.Dia AS INT)) 
       ELSE '1'  END AS Promedio
```

y me dio este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Esto no funciona: `SELECT AVG(Dia) promedio FROM tuTabla GROUP BY Dia,DiaSemana,Mes,Año` ? ... Por cierto, ¿por qué no creaste una sola columna del tipo `DATETIME`? Estás desperdiciando espacio, funcionalidades importantes y rapidez en las consultas. Aunque debo decir que tu tabla necesita seriamente ser normalizada, por ejemplo  ¿qué pasa con la columna `Semana` en ese contexto? ¿No la necesitas para los resultados? ¿Por qué no la necesitas? Es muy extraño como tienes los datos.

Comment: Gracias por su aporte @A.Cedano pero no puedo hacer lo que me sugiere porque porque mi consulta es muy extensa ademas de que poner todo el query seria confuso porque es mucha informacion y no pertenece a una sola tabla, la columna Semana si la necesito (como ya dije) y no puedo usar solo datetime porque especificamente necesito mostrar los datos asi

Comment: ¿O sea que la tabla tiene más columnas entonces? Si no muestras la tabla completa (un texto con sus columnas) cualquier respuesta que te demos será relativa. Es evidente que esta consulta necesita agrupación de datos y para agrupar tienen que cumplirse ciertos criterios. Es más, agrupar es imposible en un diseño mal concebido (como es el tuyo, por más que intentes defenderlo). Primero, el hecho de que necesites presentar datos de una forma (separados en días, mes, año) no dice que sea obligatorio guardarlos separados. Una cosa es **mostrar** datos y otra cosa es **guardar** datos.

Comment: Puedes guardar datos íntegros, y aquí no diría que *puedes*  sino que **debes** guardar tu fecha íntegra, y luego en la presentación los separas, que para eso existen funciones como `FORMAT` para separar una fecha en todas las partes posibles. Además, otro error claro de diseño en tu tabla es que se repitan tantas filas con los mismos datos. Si dices que hay más datos en la tabla, todas esas repeticiones son absurdas y se comen el espacio de la base de datos, ralentizan las consultas, dificultan todo, hacen el mantenimiento imposible. Quizá tendrías que tener una tabla asociativa o algo así.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya publique mi query completa

Answer (score 0):

/*Problema
Necesito calcular el promedio de algunos campos en sql Necesito el promedio de la columna Dia mientras tengan el mismo valor en el campo Semana, DiaSemana, Mes y Año
*/

```
select 
   t2.*, t1.promedio
from 
(
   select semana,diaSemana,Mes,Anho, avg(dia) promedio from table 
   group by semana,diaSemana,Mes,  Anho
   having count(1) > 1
) t1 join 
(
   select * from table 
) t2 on t1.semana = t2.semana and t1.diaSemana = t2.diaSemana and t1.Mes = t2.Mes and t1.Anho = t2.Anho
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, ahora no me muestra ningun dato de la consulta

Comment: intenta nuevamente, por favor. Me ensenhas que te arroja la consulta.